# sqllite query - always miss the first row - android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

I built a listview that shows data from sqllite, and it always miss the first sql row., if I add a new row , it wont show the row (even if I restart the app, it doesn't related to update). but if I add another new row, it will show the previous "new" row.

thanks for help

```
        Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("Select * from weight_listview ORDER BY `ID` DESC",null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();


      final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ////
    String[] columnames = new String[] {"C1", "C2", "C3"};
    int[] columnsR = new int[] {R.id.column1, R.id.column2, R.id.column3};


    int x=0; int fuPOINTER=0;
      final int[] fuID = new int[100];
    while(resultSet.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String d_weight = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("weight"));
        String d_date = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("date"));
        int d_id = resultSet.getInt(resultSet.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        fuID[fuPOINTER] = d_id;
        fuPOINTER++;

        x=0;
        map.put(columnames[x],d_weight);
        x++;
        map.put(columnames[x],d_date);
        x++;
        map.put(columnames[x],"i" + d_id);

        mylistData.add(map);
     }


         arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.row,columnames , columnsR);
         listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: and what did you expect with code like resultSet.moveToFirst() then  resultSet.moveToNext() ?

Comment: Remove this line: `resultSet.moveToFirst();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(resultset.moveToFirst()){//We have a result, do everything
   do{
      //get each row from resultset
   }while(resultSet.moveToNext());
}else{
   //We haven't data, show a toast
}
```

Comment: Doing by this way, you avoid the NullPointerException that is generated where table is empty or had any error trying to exec the query, cause if my mylistData is empty, will generate that error

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see how this helps you avoid an hypothetical nullpointerexception.

Comment: If you declare, initialize and assign the myListData into the IF statement, you will be sure that the resultset will ALWAYS have data for that List, anyway enclosing with try-catch block will handle that exception, but you have to ensure that these exceptions don't appears

I mean to the nullpointerexception that is generated if myListData was empty, some others lines of that code should generate the same exception

Comment: `resultset` being the cursor, and it being already assigned before the if statement, i still don't get it.